# iOS:Objective-C:Output issue due to ipad time display 12Hour / 24Hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application i am using one function to change date format to replace / with - and date format also.

When Device is set to 12 Hour, everything works fine. But when i set it to 24Hour it returns wrong value.

```
NSDate *newdate = [self convertDateSlashToDash:[obj valueForKey:@"TaskStartDateTime"]]);


//input date is  : 6/6/2017 6:38:00 PM
-(NSDate *)convertDateSlashToDash:(NSString *)dateStr{

if ([dateStr isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
    return (NSDate*)dateStr;
}

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//Set the AM and PM symbols
[dateFormatter setAMSymbol:@"AM"];
[dateFormatter setPMSymbol:@"PM"];
//Specify only 1 M for month, 1 d for day and 1 h for hour
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

// in ms 1469077819000 without ms 1469077819 for 7/21/2016 5:10:19 AM
NSTimeInterval ti = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:ti];
NSDateFormatter *formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

// [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *parsedDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

return dateString;
}
 //output of this is (24hrs): 1970-01-01 05:30:00AM

 //output of this is (12hrs): 2017-06-06 06:38:00 PM
```

Why it is not working?
Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: you are returning `dateString`?

Comment: yes, i needed that

Comment: it is wrong value, I think It is `parsedDate`

Comment: both `parsedDate` and `dateString` returns same value..only `parsedDate` is `NSDate` and `dateString` is `NSString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this line to your code to resolve that problem

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Reade more: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

The 12-hour and 24-hour are specified differently with a date formatter. Make sure that you are using the right format. I see you are using `h` for hour along with `a` at the end which configures the formatter to a 12-hour format. For a 24-hour format, you need `H` or `HH` depending on your needs. You can refer to this [link](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/) to get a better understanding of different formats

Comment: yes, but in my code input date is always in 12 hour format,and i am trying to covert that date.